# Ranker.com python beautifulsoup scraper not scraping the entire website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am working on a beautifulsoup scraper that would scrape 100 names from the ranker.com page list. The code is as follows

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/best-anime-series-all-time')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.find_all('a', class_='gridItem_name__3zasT gridItem_nameLink__3jE6V'):
    print(p.text)
```

This works and gives the output as

```
Attack on Titan
My Hero Academia
Naruto: Shippuden
Hunter x Hunter (2011)
One-Punch Man
Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood
One Piece
Naruto
Tokyo Ghoul
Assassination Classroom
The Seven Deadly Sins
Parasyte: The Maxim
Code Geass
Haikyuu!! 
Your Lie in April
Noragami
Akame ga Kill!
Dragon Ball
No Game No Life
Fullmetal Alchemist
Dragon Ball Z
Cowboy Bebop
Steins;Gate
Mob Psycho 100
Fairy Tail
```

I wanted the program to fetch 100 items from the list, but it just gives 25 items. Can someone pls help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional items come from API call with offset and limit params to determine next batch of 25 results to return. You can simply remove both of these and get a max 200 results,  or leave in limit and set to 100. You can ignore everything else in the API call apart from the endpoint.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.ranker.com/lists/538997/items?limit=100')
data = r.json()['listItems']
ranked_titles = {i['rank']:i['name'] for i in data}
print(ranked_titles)
```

Comment: is it possible to print each into a new line?

Comment: `for i in data: print(i['rank'], i['name'])`

Comment: is it possible to get the url of the image too?

Comment: print(i['url']) within loop

Comment: but adding this shows  ====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanal\Documents\tablescrape_ranker_stackoverflow.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i in data: print(i['name'], i['url'])
KeyError: 'url'
>>>

Comment: print `data[0].keys()` and have a look

Comment: got it thanks, is it possible to save the output onto an excel file?

Comment: yes. Use csv or convert to dataframe and use pd.to_csv  lots of examples on SO